# C# DataGridView with images don't show

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I need your expertise on this question:
I have a dataGridView that I fill with a table adapter

```
public contractManage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                this.tblContractsTableAdapter.FillBy(this.tESTDataSet.tblContracts);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            //Set color status
            setStatus();

        }
```

Then I want to add 3 columns (on index 8, 9 and 10) that will display a different image depending on values I have in my database
For each row I have my record Id in the first column, I query my database to get 3 values
AtrOk true/false, PrOk true/false, PoOk true/false

```
   public void setStatus()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;

        this.dataGridViewContractManage.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.ReadOnly = false;

        //Add images column
        DataGridViewImageColumn icAtr = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            icAtr.HeaderText = "ATR";
            icAtr.Image = null;
            icAtr.Name = "cImgAtr";
            icAtr.Width = 35;
            icAtr.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Columns.Add(icAtr);

        DataGridViewImageColumn icPr = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            icPr.HeaderText = "PR";
            icPr.Image = null;
            icPr.Name = "cImgPr";
            icPr.Width = 35;
            icPr.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Columns.Add(icPr);

        DataGridViewImageColumn icPo = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            icPo.HeaderText = "PO";
            icPo.Image = null;
            icPo.Name = "cImgPo";
            icPo.Width = 35;
            icPo.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Columns.Add(icPo);

        //Browse through dataGridView rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewContractManage.Rows)
        {
            //Capture contract id in first cell
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
            bool atrOk = false;
            bool prOk = false;
            bool poOk = false;

            //Query this id to get atr, pr, po status values
            //Connection string
            conn = sqlDbConnection.GetConnection();

            //Connect
            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand newCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblContracts WHERE tblContracts.ContractId=" + id, conn);

                myReader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    atrOk = Convert.ToBoolean(myReader["AtrOk"]);
                    prOk = Convert.ToBoolean(myReader["PrOk"]);
                    poOk = Convert.ToBoolean(myReader["PoOk"]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close DB connection
                conn.Close();
            }

            //MessageBox.Show("# " + id + "\nATR " + atrOk.ToString() + "\nPR " + prOk.ToString() + "\nPO " + poOk.ToString());

            //Set images in dataGridView depending on values
            DataGridViewImageCell cellAtr = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            DataGridViewImageCell cellPr = row.Cells[9] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            DataGridViewImageCell cellPo = row.Cells[10] as DataGridViewImageCell;

            cellAtr.ReadOnly = false;
            cellPr.ReadOnly = false;
            cellPo.ReadOnly = false;

            if (atrOk == true)
            {
                cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

            }
            else
            {
                cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red;

            }

            if (prOk == true)
            {
                cellPr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

            }
            else
            {
                cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red;

            }

            if (poOk == true)
            {
                cellPo.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

            }
            else
            {
                cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red; 
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

I don't get why, but it seems that the DataGridView fills correctly, set the images in the images columns send clear it leaving me with "null" in each image cell

---

After the comment from DJ Kraze, I have "played" with the connect/close (moved it out of the loop) but it doesn't change anything really.

The binding source (I have used Visual C# GUI to do it for me) is defined in my xx.Designer.cs

```
partial class contractManage
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Variable nécessaire au concepteur.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Nettoyage des ressources utilisées.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true si les ressources managées doivent être supprimées ; sinon, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Code généré par le Concepteur de composants

    /// <summary> 
    /// Méthode requise pour la prise en charge du concepteur - ne modifiez pas 
    /// le contenu de cette méthode avec l'éditeur de code.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        this.tESTDataSet = new BombardierEngAdmin.TESTDataSet();
        this.tblContractsTableAdapter = new BombardierEngAdmin.TESTDataSetTableAdapters.tblContractsTableAdapter();
        this.dataGridViewContractManage = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.tblContractsBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn();
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tESTDataSet)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridViewContractManage)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tblContractsBindingSource)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tESTDataSet
        // 
        this.tESTDataSet.DataSetName = "TESTDataSet";
        this.tESTDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // tblContractsTableAdapter
        // 
        this.tblContractsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        // 
        // dataGridViewContractManage
        // 
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8F);
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.ColumnHeadersHeight = 25;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.DataSource = this.tblContractsBindingSource;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8F);
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Name = "dataGridViewContractManage";
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowHeadersWidth = 20;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowTemplate.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.RowTemplate.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(897, 502);
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.TabIndex = 1;
        this.dataGridViewContractManage.CellContentDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridViewContractManage_CellContentDoubleClick);
        // 
        // tblContractsBindingSource
        // 
        this.tblContractsBindingSource.DataMember = "tblContracts";
        this.tblContractsBindingSource.DataSource = this.tESTDataSet;
        // 
        // agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Agency";
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Agency";
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 150;
        // 
        // endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "EndDate";
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "End";
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 80;
        // 
        // startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "StartDate";
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Start";
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 80;
        // 
        // contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ContractType";
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Type";
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 150;
        // 
        // surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Surname";
        this.surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Surname";
        this.surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "FirstName";
        this.firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "FirstName";
        this.firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        // 
        // contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ContractStatus";
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Status";
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        this.contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 35;
        // 
        // contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ContractId";
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "#";
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        this.contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 50;
        // 
        // contractManage
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridViewContractManage);
        this.Name = "contractManage";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(921, 526);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tESTDataSet)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridViewContractManage)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tblContractsBindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private TESTDataSet tESTDataSet;
    private TESTDataSetTableAdapters.tblContractsTableAdapter tblContractsTableAdapter;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridViewContractManage;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn contractIdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn contractStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn surnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn contractTypeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn startDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn endDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn agencyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource tblContractsBindingSource;
}
}
```

Comment: Brice take a look at you foreach loop it appears that you are closing the connection so if I am not mistaken you might be doing something wrong.. also where are you calling the DataGridView's DataBind() method...?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that your assigning the image to the incorrect property. You should set the **Image** property not the **Value** property.

The reason your getting null values is because when you create the column your setting the Image property to null and then never changing it.

**** EDIT ****

Try doing this instead. I've Just made it so that the creation of each object is within the same context.

```
        if (atrOk == true)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellAtr = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellAtr = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red;

        }

        if (prOk == true)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellPr = row.Cells[9] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellPr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellAtr = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red;

        }

        if (poOk == true)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellPo = row.Cells[10] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellPo.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Green;

        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cellAtr = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cellAtr.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Bullet_Red; 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Derek!! I've just checked, this works for my DataGridViewImageColumn...
Actually I'd like this property on DataGridViewImageCell!?

Comment: I've updated this, your code looks correct, however, try declaring the object type in the same context as when you are setting the value. I'm not convinced it will work, but try it anyway.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your help, unfortunately I'm still missing something as I didn't manage to make your solution work. 
I finally generate my complete dataGridView programmatically ;)
This is not a solution, but I was spending too much time trying to tweak my thing...
Thank you